# Is it possible to make own syntax rules in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

Apparently Numpy provides a special syntax for its lists. Namely I came accross the notation `myarray[:, 4]`. I tried finding the source of array in Numpy but was not successful. (I only found some C .h headers and a compiled library.)

Any idea on how someone can make their own syntax like that?

Comment: **Any** Python object can support that syntax, it is not unique to Numpy. The syntax support is part of Python.

Comment: BTW, what does `:` mean ?

Comment: @khajvah The `:` is just slice notation.

Comment: @Ffisegydd was close. `myarray[:, 4]` selects from the first array element up until the one with index `(, 4)` (a tuple). I assume, Numpy reacts to that with a custom `__getitem__()` implementation.

Comment: FYI, [pathlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib/1.0.1) uses this technique in a fantastic way: They overload `__div__()` to allow path notations like `q = p / 'init.d' / 'reboot'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short demo of using tuples to fake multi-dimensional indices:

```
>>> a={(1,2):'hi', (3,4):'there'}
>>> a[1,2]; a[3,4]
'hi'
'there'
```

Comment: Passing in tuples is not using the same grammar as extended slicing, however.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#slicings): *There is ambiguity in the formal syntax here: anything that looks like an expression list also looks like a slice list, so any subscription can be interpreted as a slicing. Rather than further complicating the syntax, this is disambiguated by defining that in this case the interpretation as a subscription takes priority over the interpretation as a slicing (this is the case if the slice list contains no proper slice nor ellipses).*

Comment: Actually this was the most intuitive answer that made me understand what's going on.

Comment: @Pithikos: Thanks! But as Martijn explained in his comment above and in his answer, the syntax Numpy is using _looks_ similar to the simple tuple notation I used in my answer, but it's actually quite a different thing internally.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is *part of the Python language*. The [*Slicing* syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#slicings) supports 1 or more slices:

> ```
> extended_slicing ::=  primary "[" slice_list "]"
> slice_list       ::=  slice_item ("," slice_item)* [","]
> ```
>
> [...] If the slice list contains at least one comma, the key is a tuple containing the conversion of the slice items; otherwise, the conversion of the lone slice item is the key.

Numpy makes use of that functionality; all you need to do is implement the [`object.__getitem__()` special method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) and handle tuples of `slice()` objects.

Now, the Numpy project did play an instrumental role in requesting that this was possible; the same applies to the use of the `...` syntax and the `Ellipsis` object, as well as to what limitations there are on the [numeric method hooks](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

The new [dedicated `@` and `@=` syntax](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) was also specifically requested by the Numpy community, for example. So in essence, if you have a compelling use-case and large enough community using the language, you can propose new syntax and have that added to the language.

Answer (score 0):

numpy only uses plain python syntax with - presumably - a smart implementation of `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` (see [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__%20getitem)).

You can play around with this notation easily, by implementing your own `__getitem__` method:

```
class Object(object):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print item
```

And see what it's doing:

```
>>> o = Object()
>>> o[:,1:2]
(slice(None, None, None), slice(1, 2, None))
```